# How to inter change magento 2 category programmatically

Tags: magento2.3.1

I would like to inter change two sub categories in magento 2. anyone help me

Comment: can you elaborate more!!!!

Comment: i have two category mens and kids.mens include a subcategory is watch and kids include a subcategory is toys.i want change the toys to mens.is it possible